# Passing back error data to .load()

Tags: jquery

I'm calling a PHP function to delete a file, using .load:

```
galleryStatus2$.load('deletePage.php', 
                {pageName : $(e.target).val()},
                function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr) {
                if(statusTxt=="success")
                    alert("External content loaded successfully!");
                 if(statusTxt=="error")
                    alert("Error: "+xhr.status+": "+xhr.statusText);
            });
```

/*  DeletePage.php  */

```
<?php

$fileName = $_POST['pageName'] . 'xml';  // comes in without a suffix
        $filePath =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/users/user_" . $_SESSION['user']['id'] . "/xmls/" . $_POST['fileName'];
        if(!unlink ($filePath)) {
                echo ("<br />delete of $filePath failed");
        }
        else {
            echo ("<br />deletePage.php: delete of $filePath succeeded");
        }

?>
```

In this case deletePage.php has serious errors.  One of the POST values it's looking for wasn't passed and the actual unlink operation fails.  But back on the client, statusTxt reports "success" and "External content loaded successfully!"

How can I tell the client from PHP that things did not go well.

Thanks

Comment: what you should be reading is response text, status text just tells you whether the webservice trigger is success/error not the response of the webservice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you probably need to read 'responseTxt' instead of 'statusTxt' (without changing 'deletePage.php':

```
galleryStatus2$.load('deletePage.php', 
    {pageName : $(e.target).val()},
    function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr) {
        if(statusTxt=="success") {
            if(responseTxt.indexOf('succeeded') >= 0) {
                alert("External content loaded successfully!");
            } else {
                alert("Error: "+xhr.status+": "+xhr.statusText);
            }
        } else if(statusTxt=="error")
            alert("Error: "+xhr.status+": "+xhr.statusText);
    }
);
```

2nd option:
.js

```
galleryStatus2$.load('deletePage.php', 
    {pageName : $(e.target).val()},
    function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr) {
        if(statusTxt=="success") {
            if(responseTxt) {
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(responseTxt);
                if(obj && obj.status == 'success') {
                    //success do whatever you need to do
                    alert(obj.msg);
                } else {
                    //fail do whatever you need to do
                    alert(obj.msg);
                }
            }
        } else if(statusTxt=="error")
            alert("Error: "+xhr.status+": "+xhr.statusText);
    }
);
```

.php

```
<?php
$fileName = $_POST['pageName'] . 'xml';  // comes in without a suffix
$filePath =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/users/user_" . $_SESSION['user']['id'] . "/xmls/" . $_POST['fileName'];
$response = array('status' => '', 'msg' => '');
if(!unlink ($filePath)) {
    $response['status'] = 'success';
    $response['msg'] = '<br />delete of $filePath failed';
} else {
    $response['status'] = 'error';
    $response['msg'] = '<br />deletePage.php: delete of $filePath succeeded';
}
json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: So the end of deletePage.php should be something like:  return {"status/error ...failed" };  ?

Comment: This is a more proper webservice response, if you want to implement in future. You can use whatever you have for now.

Comment: I don't have anything now. Perhaps you could edit your answer above to include my deletePage.php script, modified to return the proper response for a webservice, considering the webservice ran into an error.

Comment: you can refer to 2nd option